# Ruby Call to Maui or Bash

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to run a java command line operation from Ruby through a series of system commands.  The first command works fine, I never receive any success from the second (maui java command).  Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
Dir.chdir('/var/lib/maui') do

    system 'cat %s/*.txt > %s/topics.txt' % [text_path, identifier_path]
    system 'java maui.main.MauiTopicExtractor -l %s -m go_model' % [identifier_path]

end
```

I have also tried calling a bash script that processes the java commands:

```
output = %x[/var/lib/maui/process.sh #{identifier_path}]
```

However, the same result occurs-- the files are concatenated, but never reach the Maui.

When I capture the stdoutput from the maui command, I get the following (even though I have all the environment vars setup as needed and works when I run the command outside of ruby):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: maui/main/MauiTopicExtractor
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: maui.main.MauiTopicExtractor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: maui.main.MauiTopicExtractor. Program will exit
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the Maui commands work directly from the command line, do you see a process for them in the listing from `ps` after the call to `system`? Are there any logs that it might write?

Comment: I don't see it processing in the ruby script, but running directly from command line I see it...

Comment: what does system 'which java' produce?

Comment: what's in /tmp/maui.out if you replace your call to maui with: system "java maui.main.MauiTopicExtractor -l #{identifier_path} -m go_model > /tmp/maui.out 2>&1"

Comment: @rainkinz I just updated the question with a more detailed response.  I am getting the NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: which java prints out /usr/bin/java

Comment: where is your the maui jar located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment about class not found I think you need to invoke like this:

```
system 'java -cp /path/to/maui.jar maui.main.MauiTopicExtractor -l %s -m go_model' % [identifier_path]
```

if it works from the command line doing simply:

```
java maui.main.MauiTopicExtractor -l /path/to/file -m go_model
```

then can you post the output of (from the shell):

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

and from ruby:

```
system "echo $CLASSPATH"
```

Comment: Thanks bro, getting closer... I tried this:

java -cp $CLASSPATH maui.main.MauiTopicExtractor -l /path/to/dir -m go_model > /tmp/maui.out 2>&1

It needed to include too many things, so I am justing using CLASSPATH.  But now I am getting:

Unrecognized option: -l
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I run the command directly, it works fine.  This is only in ruby.

Comment: what were the results of I asked about in my answer? Also are you sure you ran:  java -cp $CLASSPATH maui.main.MauiTopicExtractor -l /path/to/dir -m go_model > /tmp/maui.out 2>&1 and not java -cp $CLASSPATH -l maui.main.MauiTopicExtractor /path/to/dir -m go_model > /tmp/maui.out 2>&1. That error is implying -l got passed to java not the MauiTopicExtractor class

Comment: I see what you're saying now...  Would you mind explaining why the environment variable wasn't exported when ruby executes it?  Once I put the $CLASSPATH variables into the command in Ruby it works...

Comment: I'm not sure your if your issue was related to the $CLASSPATH variable or the fact that java needed you to pass a the classpath explicitly (at least in the ruby version). Not sure why if it worked without that from the command line it was not being passed on to java.